Smart Boot: a kernel function to SAVE / LOAD ALL the needed working RAM from the disk
Boot process is wonderful, but quite tedious to wait the kernel reload every needed objects on the RAM again.
One day, I was wondering if it was possible the kernel to "take a snapshot" of all loaded RAM and save it to the disk with information as the count of bytes, some "magic signatures" to identify the smart boot, so that in next boot, the kernel just will have to loop the disk for ALL the data saved copying to a proper RAM location, and jump to where it should too.
I think that it could speed up the boot comparting to let the kernel load itens sequencely step by step, since is basically "one loop" to do, copying the bytes from disk do memory.
Is this possible?
I can program in Assembly and C, I know how to make a working ELF64 mixing both languages and I understand in details how the boot process works, but I would not know how to do this audacious task nor the best approaches.

Yes.  Arguably, hibernation does what you are looking for.
Also, there is a sense in which the answer is no.  There are some aspects of booting that is not about initializing RAM, but is also about resetting/initializing peripherals and resetting them.  On many computers, the time to scan for peripherals and initialize them is a large fraction of the time it takes to boot.  The type of approach you mention won't speed that part up.  So, Amdahl's law places limits on how much your type of approach will speed boot.

" is also about resetting/initializing peripherals and resetting them" . My hope was that existed a way to do it without hibernating. Thanks for the explanation
